# Visual Basic End of statement?

Tags: vbscript, compiler-errors

So when I run the following code it errors on line three saying end of statement. Any ideas?

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lnk = objShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\%USERDATA%\Desktop\Shutdown.LNK")
Dim strUserProfile as String
strUserProfile = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

lnk.TargetPath = "C:\Users\" & strUserProfile & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\shutdown.bat"
lnk.Arguments = ""
lnk.Description = "Shutdown"
'lnk.HotKey = "ALT+CTRL+F"
lnk.IconLocation = "C:\Users\" & strUserProfile & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\shutdown.bat, 2"
lnk.WindowStyle = "1"
lnk.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Users\" & strUserProfile &"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
lnk.Save
Set lnk = Nothing
```

Comment: I was hoping for the program to create a shortcut to the location after IconLocation and with the target of TargetPath. For some reason it errors declaring the variable.

Comment: It might not. It says character 20 of line 3. It may be an error with the next line.

Comment: VBScript is an untyped language. Drop the `As String`.

Comment: The rest doesn't work though. I wonder what I did wrong. Getting an error of invalid procedure on the variable lnk.

Comment: Submit a new question with your updated code and include the error description and error line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBScript, there's no such thing as a "String" object, so you can't do a Dim strMyString As String.

So in your case, you would simply do: `Dim strUserProfile`